# how to add a scrolling effect to my simple side drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-sliding

I implemented in my application the simple-side-drawer by adamrocker following the instructions that are on github:

https://github.com/adamrocker/simple-side-drawer

Code in my app:

```
//SLIDE
private SimpleSideDrawer mNav;

mNav = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
mNav.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_left_simple);
findViewById(R.id.slidemenu).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mNav.toggleLeftDrawer();

        }

});
```

this is xml of "activity_behind_left_simple"

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/leftBehindMenuScroll"
android:background="@drawable/lavagna" >

<LinearLayout

    style="@style/behindMenuScrollContent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingTop="25dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ciao"
        style="@style/behindMenuItemTitle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="General"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/matrix"
        android:background="@drawable/but_ok"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Rate"/>
```

the simple side drawer works fine, but I would like to add a scrolling effect. How can I do this?

Comment: Since Google has released their own NavigationDrawer, I would recommend using that one instead of third party implementation. See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Also I don't think you were clear about what do you mean with "Scrolling effect".. Do you want the content of your drawer scroll? Do you want drawer itself scroll (open/close animation)?

Comment: i don't use the google navigation drawer because I have problems with the API version, however i apologize if the question isn't very clear, but i want to scroll drawer itself

Comment: So you are expecting to see a slide down/up animation for the drawer menu ? Is it Correct ?

Comment: yes, exactly, correct

Answer (score 0):

If you want a scrolling effect, consider the [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) open source project.  You can demo it on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example&hl=en) if you want, but I've used it in the past with good success.

As to using the built in Android NavigationDrawer, I believe it was added to the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) so you can include that for backward compatibility if you want to go that route.